# About a room game in python

Tags: python

```
from sys import exit

def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold.  How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")

def dead(why):
    print why, "Good job!"
    exit(0)

gold_room()
```

why I input 2~9 turns out "Man, learn to type a number"
input 10~49 turns out "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
Thanks guys

Comment: `"0" in next or "1" in next` checks if 0 is in the input or 1 is in the input.  1 and 0 are both in `10~49` and neither is in `2~9`.  What do you want to happen?

Comment: Try checking [`next.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input 2, first if condition fails because there is no 0s and 1s in "2".

When you input 10 conditions are satisfied. Then `how_much` is equal to 10.

Answer (score 1):

2~9 doesn't include 1 or 0 (the program is taking it as a string, so it looks for the characters 1 or 0), so the program goes to the `else: dead()` part. You may want to just make sure that the number is in the range 1~49. Just convert the input to an int and then `if 0< how_much < 50:`

EDIT: You should try 39 (which doesn't have a 1 or 0), as an example, as you mentioned that is in the range 10~49

EDIT2: Oops, of course, thanks @PM 2Ring I forgot python could do that.

Comment: There's a better way to do the how_much test: `if 0 < how_much < 50:`